# Revealing part of your hand

Tags: rules

If a player is considering a call, can he show one of his down cards to entice a reaction from the bettor to see if he should call or fold?

Comment: Depends. Some places you are allowed to show one, some places either both or zero, some places zero. You should always ask to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

If there are any players who will act behind you, no. It is unfair to the other players to give your opponent information that might affect them.

In a tournament, no. It is unfair to use this advantage that players acting before you didn't have.

In a cash game if you are head-up, or last to act with all other players all-in, *some* clubs will allow showing cards, as this is not unethical or unfair in this situation. Ask your floorman.

Answer (score 0):

In **some** rooms if you are last to act on an all in you can show your cards.

If you are last in with a call or raise I don't think you can show.

Some times it has to be heads up, last to act, and all in.